How can we add multiple validators on single node?
I'm running a single node with 2 validators, but the block finalization stops after adding the second validator. What could be causing this issue, and how can I ensure block finalization continues smoothly?.

AURA and BABE can function in this scenario.
However, GRANDPA is not applicable. A single node is restricted to gossiping just one GRANDPA vote, even if you include several keys within it. This is a known "issue"(not really).
